# SAPUI5 (Hybrid App) Can't create entity offline

Tags: sapui5, offline

I have the following SAP UI5 snippet to create a JobSet entity.

This works online but not offline.

```
oModel.create("/JobSet", oEntry, {
   success: function(oData, oResponse) {
      self.jobId = oData.JobId;
   },
   error: function(oError) {
   }
});
```

Odata returns the new Job Id online. Offline returns blank

Answer (score 0):

When running as a hybrid offline app, operations are made against the offline store instead of directly calling the gateway service.
If you are generating any parameter after processing from backend you will not be able to get this parameter when running offline as changes are only sent to, and processed by, the backend after doing a flush and refresh - so the job id will not be available when posting offline.
If you cannot do a flush, but need to continue processing  in frontend, you can create a local id offline and fetch real job id when network connection is restored.